# How to remove internal Image padding (Top, Left and Bottom) of an Android Checkbox

Tags: android, image, checkbox, padding, android-styles

I have a Checkbox in Android with a TextView above it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_edit_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/edit_checkbox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:checked="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem with Checkbox however is that it's internal "Image" got an invisible border around it. How to remove this? I've tried `android:padding="-5dp"` but this only worked for the right side of the CheckBox for some reason, not the top, left and bottom (my main concern is the Top).

Here is a screenshot of the Checkbox in Eclipse Graphical Layout window:

*LineairLayout selected:*[image]
*Checkbox selected:*[image]

In the second picture you can see the Checkbox has some padding around it when you select it. I want to have this removed (especially on the top), so that the space between the Text and the Checkbox is reduced.

Here is a picture when I have padding="-5dp":

*Checkbox selected:*[image]

PS: If someone knows a solution with just a Checkbox and it's Text-field, so I can removed the LineairLayout and TextView, while still having the Text above the Checkbox I would also appreciate it. A single Checkbox with a custom style and Text is better for performance than a Checkbox inside a LineairLayout with an additional TextView. (I know this is more something for a different question, but I just add it here since it doesn't have a lot of priority. Everything is working already, except for the padding of the Checkbox.)

Comment: No need to change the Layout.You can get this view in LinearLayout also.See my edit on your answer

Comment: @Manishika Ah true, LineairLayout weights. Thanks for the Edit. If someone has the same problem they can choose either of the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I changed the LineairLayout to a RelativeLayout, and than I can change the margin to a minus dp. This is my end result:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_edit_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/edit_checkbox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_edit_checkbox"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:checked="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This gives the following result:

*RelativeLayout selected:*[image]

This does change the space between the Text and the Checkbox. For me this is what I want, however it still doesn't explain why the Android Checkbox' internal Image got a padding at its Top, Left and Bottom sides.. Now idea who of Android had this idea, but it was a pretty bad one.. It was better to just use no padding on the internal image and then have some default internal Margin/Padding that can be changed by users..

**OR**

**Edit :**
You can also get the same result with `LinearLayout` :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="For all products"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```